# coniferous tree and deciduous tree

Tags: vocabulaire, botanique

What would you call "coniferous tree" and "deciduous tree" in French?

suggestions:

coniferous tree =

deciduous tree = arbre à feuilles caduques

Thank you.

Comment: I'd say: "conifère"

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people would say "conifère" (including me) but if you're looking for a word that has the same value in the sentence the answers would be :

> Arbre à feuillage caduc
>
> Arbre à feuillage **persistant**

As suggested by [this link](http://www.mesarbustes.fr/blog/arbuste-caduc-persistant.html) and [this link](http://www.aujardin.info/fiches/feuillage-caduc-persistant.php).

And remember that "*caduc*" is for masculine nouns (feuillage) and "*caduque*" for feminine (feuilles).

Comment: Your first link also mentions “[des] **résineux**” as a noun, which I think is what woodsmen sometimes call the softwood conifers. I’m not sure, however, if they have an industry-specific antonym for “résineux” other than the obvious "non-résineux” for hardwoods.

Comment: Il y a des arbres à feuillage persistant qui ne sont pas résineux (ni des conifères d'ailleurs). D'après ce que je vois, il y en a peu voire pas en France donc le raccourci "feuillage persistant = conifère" est répandu. Par contre je pense que résineux et conifère désigne plus ou moins les mêmes arbres.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a classification, you probably don't want ambiguous classes. Therefore there might be an issue with your words in English because deciduous coniferous trees exist (e.g. larix decidua). So here are the pairs that you should use:

> Coniferous(or needleleaved)/broadleaved trees

```
--> Conifères/Feuillus (no need to mention "arbre")
```

> Deciduous/evergreen trees

```
--> Arbres décidus/sempervirents
```

or

```
--> arbres à feuillage caduc (arbre caducifolié)/arbres à feuillage persistant
```

Answer (score 1):

A Coniferous Tree in French is said "Un conifère". This official Larousse definition might help you : [Larousse "conifère" définition](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/conif%C3%A8re/18227)

If you want to use a complete sentence to design this kind of tree you could say "Un arbre aux fruits coniques", but most of the time the word "conifère" is used directly.

Comment: Merci, je corrige ça de suite.